# htaccess for dev folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Hello I have a prod and dev folder on the same server with the same files on the both folders and my problem is I can't access to my dev url

here my config for the root folder ( prod )

```
#AuthName "Page d'administration protégée"
#AuthType Basic
#AuthUserFile "/home/XXX/public_html/.htpasswd"
#Require valid-user

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.XXX.fr/ [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^XX.XX.XX.XX$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^XXX.fr$[NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.XXX.fr/$1 [r=301,nc]
RewriteRule ^(img|cache)($|/) - [L]

RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)-([0-9]+)$ article.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^recettes/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)-([0-9]+)$ article.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^art$ art.php$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^spots$ spots.php$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ categories.php?cat=$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
RewriteRule ^(dev/)(.*) /home/XXX/public_html/dev/$2 [L]
```

And the htaccess in my dev folder

```
AuthName "Page d'administration protégée"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/XXX/public_html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /dev/
```

Should I copy all rules from my prod in the dev htaccess ?

Comment: What error do you get when you try to access to `/dev` folder? Aren't you supposed to use a different password to access your `/dev` folder? your `.htaccess` for the dev folder is referring to the password from the root folder

Comment: I don't have an error it s just if want to access to http://www.xxx.fr/dev/news/example.php?id=9987 it redirect me to http://www.xxx.fr/

Answer (score 0):

For the **/dev** folder you have to modify the **.htaccess** file, more exactly change:

```
RewriteBase /
```

to:

```
RewriteBase /dev
```

Try again afterwards!